# get Correct value using xpath

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to use xpath to get the raw value of an element. The element is a description and it can contain raw text or xhtml.

So it can be as follows:

```
   <description>asdasdasd <a>Item1</a> asd <a> Price </a></description>
```

based on the above xml, i just need this:

```
asdasdasd Item1 asd Price
```

I've tried //description/text(), //description/descendant::*/text() and some others with no success. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
//description
```

The value of an element is its text

Or if it must be a string and there is just one element:

```
string(//description)
```